# Xcode - Where is the apply retina 4 form factor button

Tags: ios, xcode

**MYSTERY SOLVED - This is available only in the storyboard (not in a xib) and only if Auto Layout is checked to ON.**

---

OK.  This is probably a dumb question but I can't find anything on it.  All the documentation appears to be centered around using Auto Layout.  I'm not using Auto Layout.  When I open a xib, I expect to see the Layout Controls.  But this morning, I opened my xib and they are not showing up.  Did I click on something to make them go away?  Is there some place I can check to make them come back.  You know what I mean, these controls:

[image]

I use the button on the left to change back and forth from 4 to 5.  Can anybody tell me where these buttons went and how to get them back?

I am not using Auto Layout.

[image]

Comment: I know the answer.. I will post shortly...

Comment: @FahimParkar - I'll gladly give you the points instead if you can tell me how to get the apply retina 4 form factor button for a xib.  It appears that it is only available in the storyboard.  Please....correct me if I'm wrong and you'll get the points.  Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure about xib, but I posted for storyboard... I will check for xib...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you say that you don't use Auto Layout, but for me these only appear if the ViewController has "Use Auto Layout" ticked.

As I check/uncheck the option I can see the controls appearing/disappearing

Comment: I understand, but out of interest if you check the box do they appear again?

Comment: OK.  I'll give you a point for that but the apply retina 4 form factor button is still missing.

Comment: It appears as if the apply retina 4 form factor button only displays in the story board not is a xib file.  But your answer is the correct one for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You will see "Apply Retina 4.0 Form factor" at below place.

1. Select the View Controller
2. Now in Editor Menu you will see it as last option.

[image]

But for that you have to have Autolayout ticked.

---

### Edit 1

For xib, I checked and found that option is disabled.

I strongly feel because xib support iOS6 before and auto-layout is there (I think) from iOS6. And hence for xib there is no such option.

**For xib, may be above reason is not valid**. I am just think this might be the reason.

Comment: +1 but it appears that it is only available in the storyboard.  Thank you for the additional information.  I didn't know you could get it from the Editor menu.

Comment: @Lucy : I will never forget this point because when you open xcode 4 files in xcode 5, the iphone 4 automatically gets shifted to iphone 5 size and you have to click this option to get iphone 4 screens. From IB, I changed the screen size to iphone 4 but still in output I was getting screen for iphone 5. When I clicked this option, all goes well...